# How to use jnlp webstart and not cache the jar

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

We use webstart with jnlp - I would like it to not to cache in certain situations, is there a line into the jnlp xml that will cause it to not cache?

Answer (score 0):

> ..is there a line into the jnlp xml that will cause it to not cache?

No.

> **Brian Knoblauch:** Boo Oracle, I also want it to not cache for some instances.

Yay, user rules<sup>2</sup>.  It is up to the end user or their system administrator to decide the caching behavior of applications beyond *suggestions*<sup>1</sup> in the JNLP file.

1. e.g. `lazy` resources might not yet be cached, or if the cache is getting large, disposed of.
2. Very little of what Oracle builds into the JRE is for the benefit of the *developer*, it is all biased toward *user* control.

   In the end, that is 'a good thing'.  If you put all that power into the hands of developers, the user would exercise *their* power by uninstalling the Java Plug-In.

Comment: Boo Oracle, I also want it to not cache for some instances.  :-(